# Is there a maximum number of child on VirtueMart?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Joomla 2.5 / VirtueMart

Im using custom field / Plug-ins of type Stockable variants for creating childs products.

here I have a parent with 106 child, and the problem started when I'm now trying to save any change on the parent is not saved.
it's just redirect me to virtueMart dashboard.

**What's the closest thing that cost this problem?**
 **is there any limit?**
**or apache performances needed?**

I was thinking that the max_post_size is too low so I change it to 64M

Comment: Try this ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); in your admin index.php It may happen due to memory limit exceeds. This will works fine for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with many custom fields. And it was hard to find the solution. But in my case it was limitation of a POST request for max variables.
You could try to change **php.ini** variable **"max_input_vars"** (it may not be there, just add it). Set it to 2000 (1000 is default).

`max_input_vars = 2000`